# Different branch definitions for git push

Tags: git, gerrit

What is the difference between:

> git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master

and

> git push origin refs/for/master

Shouldn't the second command also push the changes to the remote repo `origin` and move the HEAD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'refspec' option is following 'repository' name.

According to --help page refspec is in the form of

```
<source ref>:<destination ref>
```

refs are usually the name of branch and it means you use 'source ref' to update 'destination ref'.
So

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
```

means update remote master using HEAD(current branch)

You can also omit 'destination ref' part. If you do so git tries to find remote branch whose name is exactly same with 'source ref'. 
 So

```
git push origin refs/for/master
```

means using local 'refs/for/master' branch to update remote 'refs/for/master' branch.

But /for/ is used by gerrit not your local repository. So git can't find local 'refs/for/master' branch and can't do anything.